# Name for structs/classes, doing compile time calculations

Tags: c++, templates, naming

I like to comment my template libary sources. It provides type containers and functionality to work with them. For example:

```
template <class TypePair>
struct first;

template <class TypePair>
using first_t = typename first<TypePair>::type;

template <
    template <class, class> class TypePair,
    class First,
    class Second
>
struct first<TypePair<First, Second>>
{
    using type = First;
};
```

Usage:

```
using my_pair = type_pair<int, double>;
using first_entry = first_t<my_pair>;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<int, first_entry >);
```

It is a compile time calculation over types. How do I call such a thing? Is there a common word for this? I know about type traits but I do not thing this term is correct here.

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: are you looking for "type traits" ?

Comment: Does this actually work?  It doesn't look like it should compile to me.  How are you using it?

Comment: Almost looks like you are trying to build an [expression template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates)

Comment: Maybe type traits is the correct term. The more I think about it, the more it sounds right.

Comment: I added a usage example.

Comment: "Type trait" sounds like a good choice. You should also look into what [Boost.MPL](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/metafunctions.html) calls "metafunction".

Comment: I go with metafunction. It sounds more general then type trait. In my simple example the first element of a pair could be seen as trait. But what if i want to reverse a type list? This does not sound like a trait.